# jQuery. Find the element where attribute isset

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes, find, where-clause

I need to find cell in specific row where isset attribute **colspan**, and no matter what it contains

im trying something like this

```
var y = 2; // for example

$table.find('tr[data-y="'+y+'"] > td:not([colspan=""])');
```

but it returns all cells in this row

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/erniesto77/6d6czukw/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to get attribute selector as it:

```
var $colspanned = $table.find('tr[data-y="'+y+'"] > td[colspan]');
```

### -jsFiddle-

Answer (score 1):

`td:not([colspan=""])');` means that you're looking for `td` with colspan different from `""` (empty string, but not undefined!). In your DOM every `td` has `colspan` with assigned value or undefined, both two different from the empty-string value.

```
$table.find('tr[data-y="'+y+'"] > td[colspan]');
```

This way you select only td DOM elements having a colspan defined.